# Why is the fontsize for axes.labelsize being ignored my matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I am trying to do some scatter plots with `pyplot`. Right in the beginning of my code, I set up some parameters with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Plot customization
size=18
params = {'legend.fontsize': size,
          'figure.figsize': (20,7),
          'axes.labelsize': size,
          'axes.titlesize': size,
          'xtick.labelsize': size,
          'ytick.labelsize': size}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

Then, I use the following code to produce the figure that follows attached:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize = (24,8))

axs[0].scatter(x = delta_pooled['Delta Placebo'], y = delta_pooled['Delta FOMC'])
axs[0].set_xlabel('Delta on Placebo')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Delta on FOMC Days')
axs[0].plot(np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2), np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2), color = 'black', linestyle = '--', label = '45° line')
axs[0].legend()

axs[1].scatter(x = delta_pooled['Pre FOMC'], y = delta_pooled['Delta FOMC'], color = 'blue')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Market Beta Right Before Announcement')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Delta on FOMC Days')

axs[2].scatter(x = delta_pooled['Pre FOMC'], y = delta_pooled['Post FOMC'], color = 'green')
axs[2].plot(np.linspace(0, 1.5), np.linspace(0, 1.5), color = 'black', linestyle = '--', label = '45° line')
axs[2].set_xlabel('Market Beta Right Before Announcement')
axs[2].set_ylabel('Market Beta Right After Announcement')
axs[2].legend()

plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.5)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

My problem here is that the labels on the axes are not responding to the `size` parameter I defined in the beginning. No matter what I do, they seem to be stuck at a given size. I had the feeling that `tight_layout()` could be generating the problem but even not using it won't fix the problem. I want the labels, ticklabels and legend to be all the same size by default.

Am I doing something clearly wrong here? What am I missing? for reproducibility, I will post the head of the data frame as a dictionary. Thanks a lot in advance!

------ DATA -------

```
{'Pre FOMC': {'AAPL': 0.9946183959470475,
  'ABBV': 1.004383171396692,
  'ABT': 0.954680213242046,
  'ACN': 0.8598662394425517,
  'AGN': 0.7588028378599108},
 'Post FOMC': {'AAPL': 1.0794312387198444,
  'ABBV': 1.0175434702901511,
  'ABT': 1.0183644649091745,
  'ACN': 0.9444666686966837,
  'AGN': 0.8832149166041097},
 'Delta FOMC': {'AAPL': 0.08481284277279688,
  'ABBV': 0.013160298893459155,
  'ABT': 0.06368425166712854,
  'ACN': 0.08460042925413203,
  'AGN': 0.1244120787441989},
 'Placebo Pre': {'AAPL': 1.1801104831160008,
  'ABBV': 1.0184393072367068,
  'ABT': 0.9720826550959236,
  'ACN': 0.8707778848440251,
  'AGN': 0.8630528618579679},
 'Placebo Post': {'AAPL': 1.1435245564111047,
  'ABBV': 1.0349768522497191,
  'ABT': 0.9855013916751156,
  'ACN': 0.9210278028935376,
  'AGN': 0.9103999896942806},
 'Delta Placebo': {'AAPL': -0.03658592670489602,
  'ABBV': 0.0165375450130123,
  'ABT': 0.013418736579192014,
  'ACN': 0.05024991804951251,
  'AGN': 0.047347127836312675},
 'Net Delta': {'AAPL': 0.1213987694776929,
  'ABBV': -0.0033772461195531456,
  'ABT': 0.05026551508793653,
  'ACN': 0.034350511204619516,
  'AGN': 0.07706495090788623}}
```

Comment: I cant reproduce your result. when I increase axes.labelsize to 2*size, the label fontsize increases. Which version and platform are u using.

Comment: That's strange, but thanks for trying to reproduce it! I have even restarted my kernel here and it does not work. I'm using Matplotlib 3.3.1 on Python 3.8.3 from Anaconda (on MacOS 10.15.6)

Comment: I got the same issue on matplotlib 3.7.0, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Bob not really. But that figure never made it into the paper I was writing so I left it at there.